# Migration from RestComm 7.6.0 to 7.8.0

Tags: restcomm

I'm using the Docker Image 7.6.0 and trying to migrate to 7.8.0, but when I do, RestComm is reset and I loose all my configurations in the workspace and database (even when they are corrected persisted when working with version 7.6.0).

I've been taking a look to the release announcement but I didn't find any useful information. Any help or link would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just some info more: the docker image 7.8.0 seems to be ignoring the ENV Variables defined when launching it in docker

Comment: Hi Anton, can you please provide the command you use to run the container. As well please provide the container startup logs: docker logs CONTAINER_ID. Have in mind that a lot of the configuration options used at 7.6.0 have been changed to the 7.8.0 release: http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Environment%20Variables.html#docker-environment